# C++11 template instance wrapping vector makes error

Tags: macos, templates, c++11, stl, stdvector

```
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <stdexcept>


using namespace std;

class NoSuchNode:public runtime_error
{
public:
    NoSuchNode(const char* str):runtime_error(str){}
    NoSuchNode():runtime_error("can not find th node"){}
};

class NodeHasExist:public runtime_error
{
public:
    NodeHasExist():runtime_error("the node has existed"){}
};

template <typename T>
struct Edge
{
    T weight;

};


template <typename X,typename Y>
class AdMatrix
{
    int num;

    map<int,unique_ptr<Y>> nodes;

    unique_ptr<unique_ptr<Edge<X>[]>[]> edges;

    bool isNode(int no);

public:
    AdMatrix(int num);


    void addEdge(int from,int to, const X & weight);
    void addEdge(int from,int to, X && weight);
    int  addNode(int no);

     Edge<X>& getEdge(int from,int to);
     Y& getNode(int no);
};



template <typename X,typename Y>
Y& AdMatrix<X,Y>::getNode(int no)
{
    if(this->isNode(no))
        return  *this->nodes[no];
    else
        throw NoSuchNode();
}

template <typename X,typename Y>
Edge<X>& AdMatrix<X,Y>::getEdge(int from,int to)
{
    if(this->isNode(from) && this->isNode(to))
        return  this->edges[from][to];
    else
        throw NoSuchNode();
}

template <typename X,typename Y>
AdMatrix<X,Y>::AdMatrix(int num)
{
    this->edges = unique_ptr<unique_ptr<Edge<X>[]>[]>(new unique_ptr<Edge<X>[]>[num]);

    for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
        this->edges[i] = unique_ptr<Edge<X>[]>(new Edge<X>[num]);
    }

    this->num = num;
}


template <typename X,typename Y>
bool AdMatrix<X,Y>::isNode(int no)
{
    auto it = this->nodes.find(no);
    if(it!=this->nodes.end())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

template <typename X,typename Y>
int AdMatrix<X,Y>::addNode(int no)
{
    if(this->isNode(no))
        throw NodeHasExist();
    else
        this->nodes[no]=unique_ptr<Y>(new Y());
    return no;
}

template <typename X,typename Y>
void AdMatrix<X,Y>::addEdge(int from, int to, const X & weight)
{
    if(this->isNode(from) && this->isNode(to))
        this->edges[from][to].weight=weight;
    else
        throw NoSuchNode();
}

template <typename X,typename Y>
void AdMatrix<X,Y>::addEdge(int from, int to,X && weight)
{
    if(this->isNode(from) && this->isNode(to))
        this->edges[from][to].weight=move(weight);
    else
        throw NoSuchNode();
}

----main

#include "AdMatrix.h"
#include <vector>

class EdgeWeight
{

    int character_t; 
    bool isEmpty_t;

public:
    EdgeWeight(){this->isEmpty_t=true;this->character_t=-1;} 
    EdgeWeight(int character)
    {
        this->character_t = character;
        this->isEmpty_t=false;
    }

    bool isChar(int character);
    void setEmpty(bool isEmpty){this->isEmpty_t = isEmpty;}
    bool isEmpty(){return this->isEmpty_t;}
};

struct Node
{
    bool isVisited;
    vector<int> edges_to; //even other container,set
    Node(){this->isVisited=false;}
};


int main(int args,char** argvs)
{
    AdMatrix<unique_ptr<EdgeWeight>,Node> matrix(5);

    matrix.addNode(1);
    matrix.addNode(2);
    matrix.addEdge(1, 2, unique_ptr<EdgeWeight>(new EdgeWeight(10)));

    auto & node = matrix.getNode(1);
    node.edges_to.push_back(1);

    return 0;
}
```

someone who ran it on Linux has not find any error. Even checked with Valgrind, and did not find any memory issues.

My develop environment:

```
 Mac OS X 10.10.2
 dialect c++11
 libc++
 Xcode Version 6.3.2 (6D2105)
```

Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: `posix`

The error:`(I can not upload the image)`

libc++abi.dylib: `terminating with uncaught exception of type std::length_error: vector`

Comment: Use gdb to debug the issue.

Comment: I has debugged the code step by step. The error happens at push_back. When allocating the memory,the new size is bigger than max_size.It is a huge num.